# PHP Extract Array with greater than sign?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

my array is looking like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Mobiles & Tablets
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [parent_id] => 1
                            [title] => Mobile Phone
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Mobile Phones
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [parent_id] => 5
                            [title] => Moto G
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3
                                            [parent_id] => 2
                                            [title] => Android
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [parent_id] => 5
                            [title] => Iphone
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => test
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 7
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => Men's Fashion
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                            [parent_id] => 7
                            [title] => Clothing
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 8
                                            [parent_id] => 12
                                            [title] => Jeans
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 9
            [parent_id] => 0
            [title] => test
        )

)
```

i write php code for extract Array.

```
public $string = '';
public $result = array();
public function getCategoryListsTree( array $items ){
    $this->createCategoryExtractNode($items);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->result);
    exit;
}
public function createCategoryExtractNode(array $items)
{
    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
        $this->string .= $value['title'].' > ';
        if(isset($value['childs'])){
            $this->string .= $this->createCategoryExtractNode($value['childs']);
        }else{
            $this->result[$value['id']] = trim($this->string,' > ');
            $this->string = '';
        }
    }

}
```

The Output is

```
Array
(
    [10] => Mobiles & Tablets > Mobile Phone
    [3] => Mobile Phones > Moto G > Android
    [4] => Iphone
    [6] => test
    [8] => Men's Fashion > Clothing > Jeans
    [9] => test
)
```

I want output like

```
Array
(
    [10] => Mobiles & Tablets > Mobile Phone
    [3] => Mobile Phones > Moto G > Android
    [4] => Mobile Phones > Iphone
    [6] => test
    [8] => Men's Fashion > Clothing > Jeans
    [9] => test
)
```

please help

Thanks

Comment: Try replacing `$this->result[]` with `$this->result[$value['id']]`

Comment: @B-and-P you are right the id issue are resolved thanks for that and please  help me to extract array like i want

Comment: I thought you got what you want already?

Comment: No, please compare both output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Globals are evil, even if they are wrapped in a fancy OO style. `$string` is a local context for each `createCategoryExtractNode` invocation. This does the job:

```
public $result = array();

public function getCategoryListsTree( array $items ){
    $this->createCategoryExtractNode($items);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($this->result);
    exit;
}

public function createCategoryExtractNode(array $items, $carrier='')
{
    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
        $string = $carrier . $value['title'].' > ';
        if(isset($value['childs'])){
            $this->createCategoryExtractNode($value['childs'], $string);
        }else{
            $this->result[$value['id']] = trim($string,' > ');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep current `path` in each moment, so lets add a respective property instead of `string` in your class definition:

```
public $path = [];
```

We push an element to `path` array on entering and pop array in the end. So `path` property array keeps current path to item. Path items are glued with ' > ' when reaching leaf node:

```
public function createCategoryExtractNode(array $items)
{
    foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
        array_push($this->path, $value['title']);
        if (isset($value['childs'])) {
            $this->string .= $this->createCategoryExtractNode($value['childs']);
        } else {
            $this->result[$value['id']] = implode(' > ', $this->path);
        }
        array_pop($this->path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This also gets the job done:

```
public function createCategoryExtractNode(array $items, $breadcrumbs =  array(), $level = 0)
 {
  foreach ($items as $key => $value) {

        $breadcrumbs[$level] = $value['title'].' > ';

    if(isset($value['childs'])){
        $this->createCategoryExtractNode($value['childs'], $breadcrumbs, $level+1);
    }else{
        $this->string = implode('',$breadcrumbs);
        $this->result[$value['id']] = trim($this->string,' > ');
        $this->string = '';
    }
}
}
```